# Procedure for exchanging a foreign driving license in Berlin

Tags: germany, driving-license, tunisian-citizens

I hope to have answer for my quetion.

I will move to live in Berlin with my husband. I have a Tunisian driving license so i need to know:

How and where can I exchange my license?

What are the essential documents I have to prepare?

Answer (score 2):

The procedure is explained [on this page](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/121598/) (in German). You don't need many documents: basically some ID, proof of residence in Berlin (you will have that after the mandatory registration), a passport photo, your current driving license (and a copy), possibly a translation.

The main difficulty is that unfortunately for you, Tunisia is not on the list of countries whose driving licenses can easily be exchanged in Germany. You will need to retake the theoretical and practical exam to get a German license (you will however be exempted from the mandatory training, you can go to the exam directly if you want to). If you don't speak German, you can also [take the exam in English, French and a few other European languages](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/in-which-languages-can-i-take-the-theory-exam-for-driving-license-in-germany).

You will also need a test of your vision and a proof that you took a special first-aid course (it takes several hours but it's quite cheap something like €15-30 plus about €6 for the vision test).

Answer (score 1):

Having gone through the procedure myself, I can say that the official page linked by Gala is not very accurate.

I wrote [a detailed post](https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/canadian-german-driving-license) about what the procedure *really* is.

1. You must know if your country has an agreement with Germany. In some cases you just need an eye test. In some cases you just need to take the theory exam. In some cases you must take the theory and practical exams. In some cases you must start over from scratch. Use [this document](https://www.bmvi.de/SharedDocs/EN/Documents/LA/driving-licence-provisions-fact-sheet.pdf?__blob=publicationFile) for reference.
2. The exams are available in multiple languages, but the translations are very unreliable. In some cases, they're completely wrong. In other cases, they make no sense. I took it in French, my native language, and struggled to understand the questions.
3. You need a lot of practice to pass the theoretical exams. Most of it is rote memorisation. The questions in the practice apps are exactly the same as the questions in the real test, word for word.
4. It takes 10+ weeks to get your licence transferred in Berlin, even if you do everything right and have no requirements. It took me about as long to get my motorcycle licence from scratch.