# Driver's license study guide for Germany in the Pakistani language

Tags: germany, driving-license

I need a driver's license study guide for Germany in the Pakistani language. I currently reside in Germany.

Comment: Please do not post personal contact details on this site. There is no guarantee that it isn't mined by spammers and scammers.

Answer (score 2):

According to the information found on [this question here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/in-which-languages-can-i-take-the-theory-exam-for-driving-license-in-germany), the test cannot be taken in Pakistani (Urdu). However, according to [another linked site in an answer on that question](http://www.lehrboegen.de/lehrboegen.html), you can purchase study material in Urdu for 95 euros. Viel Glück.